# < A > TAG occurred a strange issue when hover

Tags: html, css, hover

There is [JSFidle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BY5vQ/) that doesn't work  and here is updated which works but isn't complete [Another JSFidle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BY5vQ/1/)

the difference is there

```
<a href="#social">                  
    <div id="b-social" class="navi-ring"><p>Social</p></div>
</a>
```

`<a>` tag make it highlighted wrong from css

```
.navi-ring:nth-child(2):hover{
    background-color: #0C95C7;
}
```

It does highlight but from this

```
.navi-ring:nth-child(1):hover{
    background-color: rgb(253,225,100);
}
```

also when I add `<a>` tags to other divs it make highlight from `.nav-irin`g first child. whats wrong?

Comment: You don't need the paragraph tags.

Comment: I don't understand what does not work. Everything works fine here. (Latest Chrome)

Comment: @BramVanroy the first fiddle is not working correctly because the top 2 circles has the same background when hovered

Comment: It seems for the first 2 circles it is taking the nth child @ 1 css because they are the first child of the anchor tag that wraps them but then for 3 and 4 they styles are correct since they are the 3rd and 4th in their wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your nth-child on the anchor tags and add the anchor tags to all the 4 circles div.
But target them like

```
#brain-menu a:nth-child(x):hover navi-ring {

}
```

Your second fiddle works because circle 2-4 are under the same container

Like this

http://jsfiddle.net/BY5vQ/2/

Change the href I just did it as an example